# Linking layers using conditional spatial queries?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, spatial-analysis, function

I am looking at a drainage scheme where there are blockages in the system. The blockages are one layer. I then have a layer containing the main risk areas within the area and another layer that contains all the pipes for that entire area.

The risk areas have named references in their own attribute table, and the pipes are named using an asset ID in theirs.

What I need to do is link the pipe asset IDs to the Risk areas name references, but only if there are blockages in that risk area.

What I am aiming to do is create a new layer where the attribute table contains the pipe asset IDs, with a corresponding risk area reference (if the pipe is within a risk area) but ONLY if blockages have been reported in that risk area, otherwise, I am not interested in that risk area.
Therefore I can copy the new layer attribute table into excel and have pipes assigned to their proper risk areas.

It is for very large datasets, hence my need to automate it.

I am using QGIS 2.14.3 Essentials

essentially I want to create a formula that works like;

=IF(risk area contains blockages, Find pipes within and make new layer assigning risk area to pipes, do nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Run the **Clip** tool to output blockages in the risk area with the following parameters:

   - *Risk area* layer as the **Input layer**
   - *Blockages* layer as the **Clip layer**

---

2. Run the **Join attibutes by location** tool to output the pipes within the risk areas along with the pipe IDs with the following parameters:

   - The *Pipes* layer as the **Target vector layer**
   - The output from Step 1 as the **Join vector layer**

Comment: @Ryan - Most welcome =)